# What is a good way to attach vent covers to ceiling vents in my basement?

Tags: heating

I recently bought a house and the basement was newly renovated.

The furnace and air exchangers have vents all along the ceiling of the basement suite. However the vent covers have a tendency to fall off the ceiling and onto the floor. Is there a good way to attach them to the ceiling?

The vent covers are similar to this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the existing registers you have, the easiest thing to do is to modify it so it can be secured to the ceiling.  Drill a hole in either side of the register, and then put the register up in the ceiling and mark the holes with a pencil. Remove the register, drill holes at the marked locations, install drywall anchors, and then screw the register in place.

Comment: I think I'm going to do it this way. I have 5 of them and I think they will do the job if they would only stay in place.

Answer (score 5):

You have the wrong register cover for a ceiling. The one you have is a floor register, it just sits in place. You need a register like [this one](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-25ecodZ5yc1v/R-203213269/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=register%20covers&storeId=10051) that screws into the ceiling.
[image]

This will also distribute the heat more evenly.